# Identifying line breaks cross platform when the text comes from a QClipboard in python

Tags: python, pyqt, cross-platform, newline, paste

I'm writing a python script that takes text from the clipboard using a pyqt QClipboard object.

The script parses the pasted text as a 2D list breaking into rows at line breaks.

I use windows and in most programming languages I'm used to checking of a '\n' character to identify a line break. The problem I'm hitting is that this script needs to work cross platform and it's not working right on a Mac and after doing some digging I've discovered that a Mac line ending is classed as '\r\n' in python

How can I identify the line endings consistently cross platform?

At the moment I have two separate areas that look for line endings

This one looks for a straggling EOL character and removes it:

```
if pastedtext[-1] == '\n':
    pastedtext = pastedtext[:-1]
```

While this splits the text at each EOL

```
pasted = pastedtext.split('\n')
```

This works fine on windows but not on mac. How can I get these lines to work correctly on both systems, or is there as way I can convert the pasted text into a specific platform's line ending style before running these lines?

Is my only option to branch into two separate handling procedures after doing a string search for '\r\n' in an 'if'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [splitlines](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) is for:

```
    lines = pastedtext.splitlines()
```

which will split the text into lines in a platform-independant way. The eol characters will be stripped from the lines, unless you pass `True` as an argument.

Comment: Worked like a charm on windows, now i just gotta see if it wokrs on Mac as the pasted output is a tad... weird